# input type number in html 5 is not working?

Tags: html

```
<form name="form" method="get" action="" >
Number : 
<input type="number" name="num" id="num" min="1" max="5" required="required"/> <br/>
Email :
<input type="email" name="email" id="email"  required="required"/> <br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"  />
</form>
```

It is taking alphabets too on submitting the form.
No error messages are generated
Number type is not working.

Comment: and what browser are you trying in? html5 elements aren't supported in all browsers, you're going to have to do server-side validation to ensure no non-numbers make it through regardless.

Comment: Server-side validation should be done regardless of browser support. Regardless, if browser support is the issue, consider using JavaScript for validation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you use the input type number in HTML5:

```
<input type="number" name="cost">
```

Here is a working example of the [input type number](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number).

If you want to add validation try this:

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="cost">
```

Here is a working example of the [pattern attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_pattern).

**Note:** Both the input [type number](http://caniuse.com/input-number) and the [pattern attribute](http://wufoo.com/html5/attributes/10-pattern.html) have limited browser support.

Comment: this example is not working even

Comment: @nehathamman I don't think that the input type number provides its own validation in HTML5. I've edited my answer to show how you can use the pattern attribute to do this.

Comment: yes this is working successfully in firefox too. Thanks for the useful answer.